# Accessing main timeline through Internal Timeline - Adobe Animate - HTML 5

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, animation, adobe

I am making a animation(game) through Adobe Animate.

I want to make my character look as if he is speaking by making a frame-by-frame animation in the internal timeline so that it can repeat until he is done speaking.

If the last frame has played, and the loop has terminated, I want to go to the next frame on the main timeline.

However, I have no idea what code to insert (JavaScript) to make this happen.

I tried "MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop(2);
```

or

```
MovieClip(stage).gotoAndStop(2);
```

however,in this site you should find hundreds questions that help you solve your problem for questions like this

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, and I haven't been able to find answers as Animate is fairly new - everyone still has solutions for Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Try `exportRoot.gotoAndStop(2);`

Comment: Hello Mariyan :-) An explanation for your code would really increase your answers value. Right now, it was flagged as a *"very low quality"*. If you could explain the difference in the call of `gotoAndStop(2)` on `MovieClip(root)` and `exportRoot`, even readers who are beginners and not professionals on Adobe Animate would benefit from your answer. [From Low Quality Posts Review; Skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20976793)

Comment: I don't really care if it's flagged as 'very low quality'. The point is user asked how to write a code that access main timeline, I show him/her...This is an answer I appreciate...if you think it's low quality, so be it, I don't really care :-)